# Playing an audio without lag and can play multiple instances at the same time

Tags: javascript, audio, lag

I've been trying to make a JS app and there's this really annoying little aspect that's been bugging me recently. I just started learning JS so I don't really know the basics of JS well and can't wrap myself around the problem. It's about this button that calls a function to play an audio, but if I spam it, the audio just keeps on playing. The audio also plays with ~1 second of lag.

I tried to use .cloneNode, but it simply just doesn't work...

An example of what I want is this site: https://airhorner.com/

Here's my current code:

```js
    
var Audio = new Audio("Audio.mp3");

function funcname() {
  Audio.cloneNode(true).play();
```

Comment: Whya do you mean by “I spam … this button”?

Comment: It's like when I press it multiple times very quickly

Comment: You should get rid of `cloneNode`. That’s for cloning html elements. `Audio` is a simple Object. Not an html node.

Comment: Also you question misses all the logic of clicking a button. Since that is what you are asking about, why did you not include that part of the code?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code you provided, clicking the button will start playback. Any clicks afterwards do not do anything, since you are calling `play` on audio that is already playing.

Comment: Is there any way to start a new audio playback everytime the function is called?

Comment: You can set the time to zero. `audio.currentTime = 0`